# How to type three points diagonally?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

In an equation, I want to display three points like "...", but instead of horizontally, they should be diagonally. I'm sure there must be a command to do that, but a google search did not really help.

Any idea?

Comment: "\ddots"; see also http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: That's what I was looking for Grigory M. Thank you. Put it in an answer so I can accept it...

Comment: I looked in the tables.pdf file provided with texshop, but didn't find this specific command. I'll have a look at your other references...

Comment: @Grigory: We have had lots of questions for symbols which were easily resolved by detexify or `symbols`. I think it is better to answer them and add a link to detexify, `symbols` or the general questions, than to close them. However, you can open a question on meta to discuss this.

Comment: well, it's proposed as FAQ entry on meta — but while it's not in FAQ, I guess you're right: we'll have to answer such questions

Comment: Slightly related [MathJax and iddots / udots or reflectbox - Mathematics Meta Stack Exchange](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23273/mathjax-and-iddots-udots-or-reflectbox)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The command is called `\ddots`. See also [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol) (esp. [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html)).

Comment: Perhaps it's a good place to state that Detexify apparently runs a cryptocurrency miner

Comment: @xxx--- [citation needed]

Comment: There you go: http://tug.org/mail-archives/texhax/2011-June/017593.html

Comment: Maybe it was true 10 years ago — but nowadays detexify doesn't load anything from bitp.it (AFAICS). Also it uses very little of [client's] computer's resources — so I'm skeptical.

Answer (score 35):

According to https://texfaq.org/FAQ-mathlips

> The mathdots package (besides fixing up the behaviour of (La)TeX \ddots and \vdots when the font size changes) provides an “inverse diagonal” ellipsis \iddots

That is, `\iddots` is three dots sloping forwards while `\ddots` is three dots sloping backwards.

Comment: Codecogs doesn't support `\iddots`

Answer (score 8):

An alternative to the `\iddots` (inverse diagonal dots) from the `mathdots` package:

```
\makeatletter
\def\Ddots{\mathinner{\mkern1mu\raise\p@
\vbox{\kern7\p@\hbox{.}}\mkern2mu
\raise4\p@\hbox{.}\mkern2mu\raise7\p@\hbox{.}\mkern1mu}}
\makeatother
```

Then call with `\Ddots`

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfect but you can use `\dots` and `\cdot` and align them using subscript `_` and superscript `^` as demonstrated in row 2 below.

You get the vertical dots on row 1 as a bonus since the need to write diagonal dots are typically related to building a "dotted" matrix like in the picture below.

```
\newcommand{\vertdots}{\underset{\big{\overset{\cdot}{\cdot}}}{\cdot}} 
\newcommand{\diagdots}{_{^{\big\cdot}\cdot _{\big\cdot}}}

\begin{equation*}
A = \begin{bmatrix} 
a           & \dots         & b         \\ 
\vertdots   &  \diagdots    & \vertdots \\
c           & \dots         & d         \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
```

This produces a matrix that looks like this:

[image]

I tried to align the diagonal dots better but didn't succeed. This will be good enough for me.

Comment: Why not using `\cdots` for the horizontal dots?

Comment: I can't remember right now, but I think they didn't line up properly. But maybe it'll work.